# image control don't change the source when binding changed

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm-light

I use event in my code to notify if image was scanned

in my ViewModel :

```
public BitmapImage ImageSelected
{
   get{return _imageSelected;}
   set
   {
        if (_imageSelected == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        _imageSelected = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => ImageSelected);
   }
}

public ICommand CmdScan
{
   get
   {
       return new DelegateCommand(Scan);
   }
}
WpfTwain twainInterface = null;
private BitmapImage _imageSelected = null;

private void Scan()
{

    twainInterface = new WpfTwain();
    twainInterface.TwainTransfer += new TwainTransferReadyHandler(TwainWin_TwainTransfer);
    twainInterface.Acquire(true);
}


private void TwainWin_TwainTransfer(BitmapImage imageSources)
{
    ImageSelected = imageSources;
}
```

in My XAML

```
<Image Margin="151,12,356,12" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding ImageSelected}" />
```

when scanning multiple images the image in windows don't change until all scan complete, even I make a break point in TwainWin_TwainTransfer and it been called in evry image scanned and the RaisePropertyChanged also, and when scan is completed it show only the last image

any suggestions are welcome, I'm new in MVVM

**Update**

the code for scan in class TwainLib (called by `twainInterface.Acquire(true);` )

```
do
{
   pxfr.Count = 0;
   hbitmap = IntPtr.Zero;

   TwImageInfo  iinf = new TwImageInfo();
   rc = DSiinf( appid, srcds, TwDG.Image, TwDAT.ImageInfo, TwMSG.Get, iinf );
   if( rc != TwRC.Success )
   {
      CloseSrc();
      return pics;
   }

   rc = DSixfer( appid, srcds, TwDG.Image, TwDAT.ImageNativeXfer, TwMSG.Get, ref hbitmap );
   if( rc != TwRC.XferDone )
   {
      CloseSrc();
      return pics;
   }

   rc = DSpxfer( appid, srcds, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.PendingXfers, TwMSG.EndXfer, pxfr );
   if( rc != TwRC.Success )
   {
      CloseSrc();
      return pics;
   }
   pics.Add(hbitmap);
   BitmapImage bitmapImage = /*converting hbitmap to BitmapImage  */
   TwainTransferReady(bitmapImage); 
}
while( pxfr.Count != 0 );
```

and I also try get the  `twainInterface.Acquire(true);` in a task but same result,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced

```
private void TwainWin_TwainTransfer(BitmapImage imageSources)
{
ImageSelected = imageSources;
}
```

with

```
App.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new ThreadStart(() => ImageSelected = imageSources));
```